# Перемещение цветового пункта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. У меня есть два `div'a`, при нажатиях на первый, он меняет цвета. При нажатии на второй, он забирает выбранный цвет из первого. Как мне сделать, что бы когда второй блок забрал цвет с первого, то у первого он уже не выбирался?

Код:

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];

$(function() {
  var active_color = 'red';
  $('.block-0').click(function() {
    var color = colors.indexOf(active_color) !== colors.length - 1 ? colors.indexOf(active_color) + 1 : 0;
    $(this).removeClass('-color-'+active_color).addClass('-color-'+colors[color]);
    active_color = colors[color];
  });
  
  $('.block-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'block block-1 -color-'+active_color);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.-color-red {background-color: red}
.-color-blue {background-color: blue}
.-color-green {background-color: green}
.-color-yellow {background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block block-0 -color-red">
</div>
<div class="block block-1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например воспользоваться [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) для удаления из массива `colors` выбранного цвета *(при клике на второй блок)*

```js
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'], tmp;

$(function() {
  tmp = colors;
  var active_color = 'red';
  $('.block-0').click(function() {
    var color = colors.indexOf(active_color) !== colors.length - 1 ? colors.indexOf(active_color) + 1 : 0;
    $(this).removeClass('-color-' + active_color).addClass('-color-' + colors[color]);
    active_color = colors[color];
  });

  $('.block-1').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'block block-1 -color-' + active_color);
   colors = tmp;
    colors = colors.filter(function(c) {
      return c !== active_color;
    });

  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.-color-red {
  background-color: red
}

.-color-blue {
  background-color: blue
}

.-color-green {
  background-color: green
}

.-color-yellow {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block block-0 -color-red">
</div>
<div class="block block-1">
</div>
```

Comment: А почему цвет обратно не возвращается?

Comment: Обратно, в случаи если все цвета выбирались? Обновил ответ.

Comment: Нет, мне нужно, что бы, если цвет не выбран, то он там был. А тут цвета пропадают. Т.е. нужно, только что бы выбранного не было

Comment: Спасиибооо... :)